# How to handle continous data with several peaks

Tags: self-study, clustering, continuous-data, binning

I'm running a simulation that produces continuous data distributed in 4 to 6 peaks. Each peak is roughly normally distributed.
I'd like to detect each peak mean value and relative weight. Right now I'm manually binning it into six non uniform intervals and handling each bin separately, it works but I'd like to do it in a more automated fashion.

I guess there is a standard/common technique to process this kind of data set but I'm probably missing the right keywords to find it, could you give me some pointer?

Comment: Perhaps, what you are looking for is Gaussian Mixture.

Comment: thanks, seems promising, maybe slightly overkill for my problem but useful nonetheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using **Kernel Density Estimation** (KDE)?

If your data has clear peaks in density, that should work very well.

Methods such as Gaussian Mixture Modeling are more appropriate if you have multivariate data and difficulties choosing a good kernel bandwidth. But KDE is nuch better understood and researched.

Comment: Ok, I was looking into KDE, but there's a point that it's not that clear. Let's say I find a PDF estimate for my dataset with gaussian KDE. Then how should I proceed to find the peaks? Look for maxima and minima to cluster the data and then find each cluster parameters individually?

Comment: Yes, use maxima and minima of that function to partition your data.